# Render Method Component Bug - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm experiencing an issue correctly rendering data in a basic component?

*questionThree.js*

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import List from '@material-ui/core/List';

    import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

    import Android from "@material-ui/icons/Android";
    import Pets from "@material-ui/icons/Pets";
    import BugReport from "@material-ui/icons/BugReport";

    import QuestionListItem from './questionListItem';
    import { createRowData } from './mocks';

    const createMockData = () =>{
        /* Please do not refactor this function */
        return [
            createRowData({species: 'Robot', name: 'T-100', Icon: Android, description: "Likes long walks, walking over the bones of it's enemies"}),
            createRowData({species: 'Bug', name:'Barry', Icon: BugReport, description: "Likes long walks, and creating problems in all your code"}),
            createRowData({species: 'Rabbit', name:'Roger', Icon: Pets, description: "Likes long walks and getting to know the inner you"}),
            createRowData({species: null, name: null, Icon: null, description: null}),
        ]
    };

    const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
        container:{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: '100%',
        },
        root: {
            width: '100%',
        },
        inline: {
            display: 'inline',
        },
    }));

    class questionThree extends Component {
        render(){
            const classes = useStyles();
            const mockData = createMockData();
            return (
                <div className={classes.container}>
                    <Paper>
                        <List className={classes.root}>
                            {mockData.map((item, i) =>{
                                return <QuestionListItem item={item} key={item.id} divider={i !== mockData.length -1}/>
                            })}
                        </List>
                    </Paper>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default questionThree

*question.js*

import React from 'react'
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Solution from './images/solution.png'
import { CardMedia } from '@material-ui/core';
const question = ()=>{
    return (
        <div>
            <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
                Question Three
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                List on the fritz
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                This task revolves around a bug in the render method of a basic component.
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                Your task if you choose to accept it, is to resolve this bug (displayed on the right and in the console) .
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                As with all the questions in this tech test, you may or may not wish to refactor some of the code.
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
                Below is what the final solution should look like. (GUID'S will vary)
            </Typography>
            <CardMedia
                image={Solution}
                style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 500,
                    backgroundSize: 'contain',
                }}
                title="The Solution"
            />
        </div>
    )
};

export default  question
```

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import QuestionThree from './questionThree';
import Question from './question'
import ErrorBoundary from '../../components/errorBoundary'
const questionThree = () =>{
    return (
        <ErrorBoundary question={Question}>
            <QuestionThree/>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    )
}

export default questionThree;
```

I've tried a number of solutions and most of the solutions available on Google and nothing seems to work. I did try the solution provided at https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html, however I hit an issue with getting the results back from the second step of the instruction.

What am I missing? Is this a 'I should've gone to Specsavers' moment?

Answer (score 0):

`makeStyles` returns a hook called `useStyles` which can only be called inside a functional component. That is why you are getting the error.

In your case change `questionThree` to be a functional component

```
const questionThree = (props) =>  {
   const classes = useStyles();
   const mockData = createMockData();
   return (
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <Paper>
                    <List className={classes.root}>
                        {mockData.map((item, i) =>{
                            return <QuestionListItem item={item} key={item.id} divider={i !== mockData.length -1}/>
                        })}
                    </List>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        );
}
export default questionThree
```

To use it for class components, make use of `withStyles HOC`

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

   const styles = {
        container:{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: '100%',
        },
        root: {
            width: '100%',
        },
        inline: {
            display: 'inline',
        },
   }
   class questionThree extends Component {
        render(){
            const {classes} = props
            const mockData = createMockData();
            return (
                <div className={classes.container}>
                    <Paper>
                        <List className={classes.root}>
                            {mockData.map((item, i) =>{
                                return <QuestionListItem item={item} key={item.id} divider={i !== mockData.length -1}/>
                            })}
                        </List>
                    </Paper>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default withStyles(styles)(questionThree);
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. Generates errors. Can you clarify where you're suggesting I deploy your changes. I changed my questionThree.js to match your two suggestions and it just came back stating that useStyles is not a React function. What am I missing?

Comment: I have suggested you two approaches. In the first one you can convert your class component to a functional component. In the second one you can use withStyles HOC. 

Its up to you to follow one of the two approaches. Also if you are following the first approach make sure you have react version >=16.8.0

Comment: Thanks. I'm using react >=16.10.2 and react-dom >=16.10.2. Is that a problem?

Comment: No the versions are correct. Did you try the first approach?

Comment: I replaced ln39-56 in questionThree.js with your first solution and get the following error: 

Line 59:18:  React Hook "useStyles" is called in function "questionThree" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: Ok, I think the issue here is because the component name need to start with uppercase character. Please change it to QuestionThree instead of questionThree

Comment: Doing that and updating the references to it results in a new error:
Line 5:7:  Parsing error: Identifier 'QuestionThree' has already been declared